# Excel VBA text file import skip column

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, import

I need to import a drill table text file to get some information out of it. I would like to not import some delimited columns.

By hand with the import text tool, I can select the columns and change their "Column data format" to "Do not import column (skip)". My script actually is only able to import the data with the delimiters that I need. I couldn't find a way to skip the columns I don't need. Like the column 1,3,5..... and others.

Here is my code:

```
Sub ImportTextFile()
Dim fName As String

ActiveSheet.Range("$A:$M").ClearContents

fName = Application.GetOpenFilename("Drill table, *.tap; *.drl")
If fName = "False" Then Exit Sub

    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="TEXT;" & fName, _
        Destination:=Range("$A$20"))
            .Name = "sample"
            .FieldNames = True
            .RowNumbers = False
            .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
            .PreserveFormatting = True
            .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
            .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
            .SavePassword = False
            .SaveData = True
            .AdjustColumnWidth = True
            .RefreshPeriod = 0
            .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
            .TextFilePlatform = 437
            .TextFileStartRow = 1
            .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
            .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierNone
            .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = True
            .TextFileTabDelimiter = True
            .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
            .TextFileCommaDelimiter = False
            .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = True
            .TextFileOtherDelimiter = "=" & Chr(9)
            .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
            .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False

    End With

End Sub
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Set `.TextFileColumnDataTypes` properly (9 - skip, see XlColumnDataType enumeration).

Comment: Thank you very much. I used that code 
.TextFileColumnDataTypes = _
                Array(xlSkipColumn, xlSkipColumn, xlSkipColumn, xlGeneralFormat, xlSkipColumn, xlSkipColumn, xlGeneralFormat, xlSkipColumn, xlSkipColumn, xlGeneralFormat)